# Monitoring Ehcache via JMX

Tags: spring, ehcache

I have implemented application in Spring + Hibernate. To optimize ORM operations I have followed by [this](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/How-to-monitor-Ehcache-in-JMX-with-Spring-Configuration) tutorial to enable monitoring for Ehcache:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableCaching
...
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ....

    @Bean
    public EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCacheManager((net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager) ehCacheManagerFactory().getObject());

        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactory() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public ManagementService managementService() {
        return new ManagementService(ehCacheManager().getCacheManager(), mBeanServer(), true, true, true, true);
    }


    @Bean
    public MBeanServer mBeanServer() {
        MBeanServer bean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        return bean;
    }
}
```

However I cannot see any ehache beans in jConsole:

[image]

Do you know if I missed something to enable statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that you are simply creating the `ManagementService` but not initialising it.

Your `managementService` method needs to invoke the `init()` method on the created `ManagementService`.

Unless you effectively need access to the `ManagementService` for other purposes, exposing it as a bean is not required and you may replace this by a usage of the static `ManagementService.registerMBeans(CacheManager, MBeanServer, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean)` either inside the `ehCacheManagerFactory()` or `ehCacheManager()` methods.

The static method creates the `ManagementService` and initialises it.