# Tomcat jmx is missing ehCache entries

Tags: tomcat, jmx

I have an application on tomcat 7 on a server where i can connect to jmx console and see ehcache statistics.

I deployed the same application in a local tomcat and when i try to connect to jmx console i cannot see any ehcache entries in mbeans

Is there any extra config in tomcat i missed?

**Server version:**

```
tomcat : Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
java :  1.8.0_144-b01
```

**Local version:**

```
tomcat  : Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
java :  "1.8.0_144"
```

thanks

Comment: OS of both servers ?

Comment: local : windows
and  
server : linux

Comment: You should have started your question with that ;)

Comment: Why there any know issue on windows ? 
In windows i can see almost all entries that i have in linux. i'm just missing this one and 2 others

Comment: I suggest you editing the question title to say Windows is somewhat guilty. Add tags too, this will give focus to your question.

Comment: Try setting JMX to be firewall-compatible : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener

Comment: Arg still same issue

Comment: It doesn't look to be a config issue then. Did you code anything, such as this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496432/7748072 ?